# How to convert user input datetime into UTC and store in database with remote server in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc, toisostring

I have a datetime which is from user input. And need to store into database.
The output of date in console.log() in remote server is different from local server.

Data from user input:

```
ui_date = '2018-05-23';
ui_time = '10:00'; // literally meant for 10 oclock
//.... i manage to concatinate ui_date and ui_time and convert to ISO datetime
```

Now...
Output from local server

```
console.log(myDate.toISOString());  
// outputs: 2018-05-23T02:00:00.000Z
// This is correct UTC since I'm in philippines and the offset is +8
// Localserver automatically convert it to UTC
```

Output from remote server

```
console.log(myDate.toISOString());  
// outputs: 2018-05-23T10:00:00.000Z
// This is wrong because it is in local time not UTC
```

It seems remote server cannot convert this datetime into UTC.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

**UPDATE**
showing the actual code:
By the way I'm using node.js as a server.

Input from user:

```
{
    "date": "2018-05-23",
    "time": "10:00"
}
```

my route:

```
router.post('/test_datetime', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.date);
    console.log(req.body.time); 

    var date = req.body.date;

    // get the date, month and year
    var dd = new Date(date).getDate();
    var mm = new Date(date).getMonth();
    var yy = new Date(date).getFullYear();

    // get the hour and min from "10:00" and convert to number
    var hour = parseInt(req.body.time.substr(0, 2));
    var min = parseInt(req.body.time.substr(3, 4));

    // constructed datetime
    var datetime = new Date(yy, mm, dd, hour, min).toISOString();
    console.log(datetime);
});
```

local server output of datetime:

```
2018-05-23T02:00:00.000Z
```

Remote server output of datetime:

```
2018-05-23T10:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that constructs the ISO8601 date time string? Can you also show us how the datetime is passed between servers?

Comment: Your assertion that "2018-05-23T10:00:00.000Z" is not UTC is incorrect. The "Z" indicates the time zone as UTC. See the UTC section on ISO8601 from Wikipedia for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)

Comment: I updated my post. thanks

Comment: read phuzi's comment again - your wetware needs an update, not your post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your construction of the JavaScript Date because the method you use doesn't take in to account the client's offset to UTC.

Creating a new date from the date string, as your code does initially, will assume the date (and time) is local.

Then just setting the hours and minutes on that date will keep everything in sync.

```js
let date = '2018-05-23';
let time = '10:00';

// parse the date and time using the local timezone info
let d = new Date(date + ' ' + time);

// Generate the UTC ISO string
let isoDateTime = d.toISOString();
console.log(isoDateTime);
```

Comment: The same output in the remote server Sir. 2018-05-23T10:00:00.000Z

Comment: I used ec2 instance with ubuntu os in AWS.

Comment: Could you add to your question how the datetime is passed to the remote server?

Comment: I think it's not about that. Because i tried your code also and test both local and remote server, and the output is still the same like mine.

Comment: When you say "local server" in your question do you mean the browser or another server before it hits AWS?

Comment: @noyruto88 You may not think it's "not that" but without the code we cannot confirm.

Comment: I have local server running with node js, and mongodb. The same in my remote sever setup with ec2 instance of AWS amazon. I put your in mine to test and then push to my repo and in remote server i pull your code to test. That's how i do. Thanks.

Comment: That's great we still need to see the code on the client, your local server and the remote server. As there appears to be an issue on the remote server the issue is likely with either the sending/serialization or the receiving/deserialization of the data. __PLEASE ADD YOUR CODE__

Comment: I know the problem now, Remote server cannot get the timezone offset, because when i run this code in remote server new Date().getTimezoneOffset() it returns 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171677/discussion-between-phuzi-and-noyruto88).